# Redireccionar un formulario despues de hacer clic sobre un botón

Tags: javascript, jquery

En el código hay un formulario hecho con jquery que tiene control de errores, pero necesito que me redirija a otra página si no hay errores: por ahora no necesito almacenar la información. No consigo solucionar el problema que tengo.

```html
    <div class="editarProyecto">
        <button type="submit" id="submit">Editar Proyecto</button>
    </div>
</form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#formulario').submit(function(event) {
            var errores = false;
                  

            if ($('#descripcion').val() == "") {
                errores = true;
                $('#descripcion').addClass('inputerror');
                $('#descripcion_help').html("Campo vacío").addClass('error');
            } else {
                $('#descripcion').removeClass('inputerror');
                $('#descripcion_help').html("").removeClass('error');
            }

            if (errores) {
                $('#errorMsg').html("Hay errores en el formulario").show();
                event.preventDefault();
            } else {
                window.location.href = "paginaPrincipalGestor.html";
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: en *window.location.href = "paginaPrincipalGestor.html";* agrega el  local del archivo donde estas por ejemplo:  *window.location.href = "localhosst:4200/paginaPrincipalGestor.html";*

Comment: La llamada a `event.preventDefault()` deberías hacerla al inicio del todo dentro de tu función manejadora, de lo contrario, si no hay errores, se realizará el envío del formulario que es el comportamiento por defecto del evento.

Comment: solo aclarando, los formularios se hacen con HTML, no con javascript/jquery.

Comment: esto no te funciona: window.location.href = "paginaPrincipalGestor.html"; sale algo en la consola, necesita hacer debug e identificar el contenido de errores cuando no los hay ...

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover se pueden crear formularios de forma programática con JS/Jquery y nisiquiera se mostraría en la vista con HTML.

Comment: @MauricioContreras y eso es lo que el OP coloco en su publicación???

Comment: como primer paso debes evitar que el formulario se envíe para poder hacer las comprobaciones, por lo que el event.preventDefault() debe ir al inicio de la función. luego en if (errores)  puedes hacer un form.submit() para enviar el fomrulario solo si se cumple esa condición.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando envías el formulario, la página se recarga. Por lo tanto, cualquier cambio que hagas en la ubicación de la ventana se perderá cuando la página se recargue.

Puedes cambiar el comportamiento para que antes no te pase eso:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#formulario').submit(function(event) {
        var errores = false;

        if ($('#descripcion').val() == "") {
            errores = true;
            $('#descripcion').addClass('inputerror');
            $('#descripcion_help').html("Campo vacío").addClass('error');
        } else {
            $('#descripcion').removeClass('inputerror');
            $('#descripcion_help').html("").removeClass('error');
        }

        if (errores) {
            $('#errorMsg').html("Hay errores en el formulario").show();
        } else {
            event.preventDefault(); 
            window.location.href = "paginaPrincipalGestor.html"; 
        }
    });
});
```